# How to bind a Database Datetime object to a class property?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a table with a row defined as this:

```
[LastModification] DATETIME DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL
```

In an ASP.NET project it's being mapped to a class field:

```
public DateTime LastModification { get; set; }
```

When I try and add a new record, it crashes and reports the error:

> The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value.

Any ideas on what's going wrong here?

Comment: Are you setting a value for LastModification? I.e. you have it set to be NOT NULL at the database level.

Comment: SQL DateTime and DateTime2 are not the same (DateTime2 has a larger range and precision) Perhaps you are trying to save DateTime.MinValue (1//1/0001) which is OK for DateTime2 but out of range for DateTime which has a minimum value of 1/1/1751

Comment: No, I'm not setting a value for LastModification. My understanding is that the getdate in the default should take care of that for me. There is no mention of Datetime2 in the declarative space anywhere from me.

Comment: The property `LastModification` of your POCO class is of type `DateTime`. The C#/ASP.NET `DateTime` maps to the SQL `DateTime2`. See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx). Most likely, your error occurs when you are saving back to the database because, as Stephen Muecke pointed out, a C# `datetime2` value doesn't fit into the valid range of a SQL `datetime`. Also, `GetDate()` will only work as a default if it is not explicitly set in an `Insert` statement. MVC is probably attempting to explicitly set a value.

Comment: So I have to use Date in the T-SQL declaration right? Is there a default I can use in the database side of things then to mimick that auto timestamp I need upon insertion of a new record? Stick all this in a reply btw, I'll accept the answer. Helpful. Thanks.